# Find out co-occurence of some integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame like the following (the sequence in each row does not matter):

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  2  2  3  4
2  3  2  5  6
3  1  2  7  8
4  2  2  9  0
5  3  2  2  1
6  1  2  4  3
7  2  2  6  5
8  3  2  8  7
9  1  2  0  9
```

I'd like to find out probability of each number of range(1,9) co-occurency with another. In my mind, I'm picturing the result like following:

```
   1     2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  
1  1     0.2  0.3  0.4  0.1  0.8  0.1  0.3  0.8 
2  0.1   1    0.3  0.4  0.1  0.8  0.1  0.3  0.8 
3  0.1   0.2  1    0.4  0.1  0.8  0.1  0.3  0.8 
4  0.1   0.2  0.3  1    0.1  0.8  0.1  0.3  0.8 
5  0.11  0.2  0.3  0.4  1    0.8  0.1  0.3  0.8 
6  0.1   0.2  0.3  0.4  0.1  1    0.1  0.3  0.8 
7  0.1   0.2  0.3  0.4  0.1  0.8  1    0.3  0.8 
8  0.11  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.1  0.8  0.1  1    0.8 
9  0.11  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.1  0.8  0.1  0.3  1
```

Are there any functions from pandas that can do this?

Comment: would you mind explain the logic here ?

Comment: Do you just want all pair-wise conditional probabilities  that given X on a row, Y also exists on that row?

Comment: Why is the matrix not symmetric if order does not matter?